# AVG 9 (Internet Security Business Edition) and IIS 6.0

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, anti-virus

Are any of you using AVG 9 Internet Security Business Edition along with IIS 6.0 and if so have you experienced problems?

We just went from 8.5 to 9.0... Luckily I tried on only one of the servers in the web farm first to run for a week to make sure it played well with my servers.  A few hours after the install all web apps were giving a "connection refused" error.  Neither iisrest or restarting world wide web publishing services resolves the issue, only rebooting the machine brings the webs back up.  They are all ASP.Net sites by the way (v2.5).  What's interesting is if I take the machine out of the load balancer, the machine runs fine and the webs are just fine for days... as soon as i put it back in the pool it's only a few hours before its sad.

The only thing I can think of right now is that the Resident Shield may be causing an issue, any thoughts?

Comment: Any What do the AVG/IIS logs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can figure is that something went wrong on the during the install of AVG.  After removing it entirely and re-installing it everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried temporarily disabling the resident shield to find out if that's the problem?

Did you install the AVG firewall along with AVG9?

Are there any logs that AVG generates that you can look through?

Comment: I should have added more specifics to the original post... no there is no firewall installed - I know why you'd ask that but no.. I'm smart enough to not miss that one ;).

I want to be able to monitor during the day (normal business hours) so I plan on turning off resident shield tomorrow morning and trying it - however I really don't want to run without it.  I'm wondering if I need to exclude IIS related directories and my application directories from it's scans.

Comment: Oh also yes there are logs, however nothing that leads me to believe anything is "out of the normal" for it.

Comment: Do you notice any kind of unusual activity (cpu/mem) with the real time scanner process? AVG doesn't sell a product specifically for servers and I have had more than a few problems running on Win2k3 (perfectly fine on XP/Vista/7 though). I'm wondering if it sees your IIS activity as virus-like and blocks it. You could also try using a tool like Process Explorer to see what files the AVG executables are looking at.

Comment: The cpu and memory were all low, as soon as the machine's IIS went "down" activity on the box drops to pretty much zero.  I can see where it could think it's virus-like activity but it sure seems like it should be TELLING me that, know what I mean?

Comment: Have you tried excluding IIS directories from Resident Shield and/or totally disabling it? Also, what about setting IIS's max connection count very low? I wonder if it's the number of simultaneous connections that scares AVG.